# how to create independent sum of a nested array of 3 levels

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to add the values ​​to a nested array with 3 levels, I have already managed to do the first level, but the second level and third level have been difficult for me. I need to do the reduce sum for the sector and category.

I need to specify each variable of each level since I have to show those values ​​in a nested table in this link I show you what I'm trying to do--> https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-cc85fm

here I leave the example array

```
DATA = [
  {
    "mercado": "AGROALIM",
    "sector": [
      {
        "sector": "AGRICOLA",
        "rubro": [
          {
            "rubro": "FORRAJE",
            "v48": 0.65046,
            "a0": 0.63372546,
            "a1": 0.65046,
            "a2": 0.65046,
            "a3": 0,
           
          },
          {
            "rubro": "FRUTAS",
            "v48": 3.0869145,
            "a0": 0.34910247,
            "a1": 3.0869145,
            "a2": 3.0869145,
            "a3": 0.24792662,
            
          },
          {
            "rubro": "UVAS",
            "v48": 2.3387132,
            "a0": 0,
            "a1": 2.3387132,
            "a2": 2.3387132,
            "a3": 0,
            
          },
          {
            "rubro": "VEGETALES",
            "v48": 54.80923,
            "a0": 25.5776,
            "a1": 54.80923,
            "a2": 54.80923,
            "a3": 6.0376153,
           
          }
        ],
        "v48": 60.88532,
        "a0": 26.560429,
        "a1": 60.88532,
        "a2": 60.88532,
        "a3": 6.2855415,
        
      },
      {
        "sector": "ALIMENTOS",
        "rubro": [
          {
            "rubro": "BEBIDAS",
            "v48": 1.2313427,
            "a0": 0.16636576,
            "a1": 1.2313427,
            "a2": 1.2313427,
            "a3": 0.61833805,
          
          },
          {
            "rubro": "CECINAS",
            "v48": 12.669079,
            "a0": 7.1717906,
            "a1": 12.669079,
            "a2": 12.669079,
            "a3": 2.115978,
            
          },
          {
            "rubro": "CONSERVAS",
            "v48": 33.866325,
            "a0": 8.312485,
            "a1": 33.866325,
            "a2": 33.866325,
            "a3": 12.918893,
            
          },
          {
            "rubro": "HARINA",
            "v48": 3.7472982,
            "a0": 0.011847539,
            "a1": 3.7472982,
            "a2": 3.7472982,
            "a3": 0,
           
          },
          {
            "rubro": "LACTEOS",
            "v48": 5.181415,
            "a0": 0,
            "a1": 5.181415,
            "a2": 5.181415,
            "a3": 0,
          
          },
          {
            "rubro": "VINO",
            "v48": 6.591118,
            "a0": 4.3435507,
            "a1": 6.591118,
            "a2": 6.591118,
            "a3": 0,
            
          }
        ],
        "v48": 63.28658,
        "a0": 20.006039,
        "a1": 63.28658,
        "a2": 63.28658,
        "a3": 15.653209,
     
      },
      {
        "sector": "ANIMALES",
        "rubro": [
          {
            "rubro": "ANIMALES",
            "v48": 0,
            "a0": 0,
            "a1": 0,
            "a2": 0,
            "a3": 0,
           
          },
          {
            "rubro": "CRIANZA",
            "v48": 7.259204,
            "a0": 3.696346,
            "a1": 7.259204,
            "a2": 7.259204,
            "a3": 1.4296815,
            
          }
        ],
        "v48": 7.259204,
        "a0": 3.696346,
        "a1": 7.259204,
        "a2": 7.259204,
        "a3": 1.4296815,
        
      },
     
    ],
    "v48": 665.07355,
    "a0": 198.37775,
    "a1": 665.07355,
    "a2": 665.07355,
    "a3": 129.8242,
    
  },
  {
    "mercado": "COMERCIO",
    "sector": [
      {
        "sector": "DST MATERIALES",
        "rubro": [
          {
            "rubro": "ACERO",
            "v48": 59.89149,
            "a0": 13.750453,
            "a1": 59.89149,
            "a2": 59.89149,
            "a3": 5.890896,
         
          },
          {
            "rubro": "DST MATERIALES",
            "v48": 4.495523,
            "a0": 0,
            "a1": 4.495523,
            "a2": 4.495523,
            "a3": 4.104237,
           
          },
          {
            "rubro": "M CONSTRUCCION",
            "v48": 4410.735,
            "a0": 1214.6946,
            "a1": 4410.735,
            "a2": 4410.735,
            "a3": 519.7534,
            
          },
          {
            "rubro": "M ELECTRICO",
            "v48": 115.70385,
            "a0": 28.76517,
            "a1": 115.70385,
            "a2": 115.70385,
            "a3": 14.594371,
            
          },
          {
            "rubro": "TORNILLOS",
            "v48": 16.949966,
            "a0": 13.514951,
            "a1": 16.949966,
            "a2": 16.949966,
            "a3": 0,
           
          }
        ],
        "v48": 4607.7754,
        "a0": 1270.7251,
        "a1": 4607.7754,
        "a2": 4607.7754,
        "a3": 544.34296,
         
      },
      {
        "sector": "DST UTILES",
        "rubro": [
          {
            "rubro": "U AUTOMOTRIZ",
            "v48": 553.1792,
            "a0": 114.20921,
            "a1": 553.1792,
            "a2": 553.1792,
            "a3": 143.01349,
           
          },
          {
            "rubro": "U MINERIA",
            "v48": 159.25165,
            "a0": 52.779083,
            "a1": 159.25165,
            "a2": 159.25165,
            "a3": 15.5641575,
           
          },
          {
            "rubro": "U OFICINA",
            "v48": 1.7601775,
            "a0": 0.33449724,
            "a1": 1.7601775,
            "a2": 1.7601775,
            "a3": 0.12675817,
            
          },
          {
            "rubro": "U SALUD",
            "v48": 1.2493496,
            "a0": 1.2493496,
            "a1": 1.2493496,
            "a2": 1.2493496,
            "a3": 0,
            
          },
          {
            "rubro": "U TALLER",
            "v48": 1033.7096,
            "a0": 202.98636,
            "a1": 1033.7096,
            "a2": 1033.7096,
            "a3": 251.42595,
           
          },
          {
            "rubro": "U VESTIMENTA",
            "v48": 0.12437412,
            "a0": 0,
            "a1": 0.12437412,
            "a2": 0.12437412,
            "a3": 0,
            
          }
        ],
        "v48": 1749.2743,
        "a0": 371.5585,
        "a1": 1749.2743,
        "a2": 1749.2743,
        "a3": 410.13034,
        
      }
    ],
    "v48": 6357.05,
    "a0": 1642.2837,
    "a1": 6357.05,
    "a2": 6357.05,
    "a3": 954.47327,
    
  }]
```

Here is an example of what I do as the first level, which is the market, I would need to reduce the sector and item item, each variable of the first level array is

```
let this.mercadoData= DATA;
  public calculateTotal(item: string) {
    return this.mercadoData.reduce((accum, curr) => accum + curr[`${item}`], 0);
  }
```

This is the result that I want to get where the accumulated value of each variable will be shown in the table for each level, so I need to perform the accumulated reduction for each field by array level
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOc47.png)

Comment: if you are linking offsite to a stackblitz, you should still include a copy of your relevant code in your question in addition to the link https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you please reduce your example a bit. For explaining what you want to do, there is probably no need for hundets of number. And also include your expected results for that reduced example ...

Comment: Here is the example of what I want to do to accumulate each value of each level of the array and then display it in a footer table  https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-cc85fm